# How to add two kind of sorting in Android?

Tags: android, sorting, listview

I have a custom class which implements `Comparable`, with an implemented method. My code:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Car car) {

    String tmp = price.replace(" €", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
    String tmp2 = car.price.replace(" €", "").replaceAll(" ", "");

    Integer p1 = Integer.valueOf(tmp);
    Integer p2 = Integer.valueOf(tmp2);

    return p1.compareTo(p2);
}
```

Then I call `Collections.sort(carList);` and notify my adapter. Now, I would like to implement a similar method with returning `p2.compareTo(p)` for descending order but I didn't succeed.

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Same but `return p2.compareTo(p1)`?

Comment: But where do I write this method ? And how do I use it when I call Coolections.sort(list), to tell it to use the second method rather than the 1st one ?, Because  I can't override the method twice in my Car class..

Comment: Instead of implementing `Comparable` in your class, you should write 2 `Comparators` and pass them to `Collections.sort(Collection, Comparator)` depending on which sorting you want to do. Also note you can do it like you're doing right now and just reverse the sorted list when needed.

Comment: @m0skit0 thanks for helping, so you mean that 2 comparators are 2 classes right ?

Comment: Yes, 2 different classes that implement `Comparator`.

Comment: @m0skit0 thanks for helping ! Post it as an answer so I can accept it, cheers

Comment: In Java 8: `Collections.sort(cardList, Comparator.reverseOrder())`. Or `cardList.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of implementing `Comparable` in your class, you should write 2 `Comparator`s and pass them to `Collections.sort(Collection, Comparator)` depending on which sorting you want to do.

Note you can do it like you're doing right now and just reverse the sorted list when needed.